# crop and upload photo using croppie.js ajax php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using a jquery crop plugin called croppie to crop an image before the user uploads the image into the database but for some reason, the image is inserted into the upload folder but the sql query doesn't work. Pls could anyone help me out

the html markup.

```
<input type="file" id="upload">
<br/>
<button class="btn btn-success upload-result">Upload Image</button>
```

The js for cropping and sending the photo to testcrop.php with ajax.

```
$uploadCrop = $('#upload-demo').croppie({
    enableExif: true,
    viewport: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        type: 'circle'
    },
    boundary: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300
    }
});

$('#upload').on('change', function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
        }).then(function () {
            console.log('jQuery bind complete');
        });

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "components/testcrop.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image": resp},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'Image Uploaded Successfully') {
                    html = '<img src="' + resp + '" />';
                    $("#upload-demo-i").html(html);
                } else {
                    $("body").append("<div class='upload-error'>" + data + "</div>");

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

testcrop.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require('../includes/settings.php');

$data = $_POST['image'];
list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$imageName = time() . '.png';

if ((($data == "image/gif") || ($data == "image/jpeg") || ($data == "image/jpg") || ($data == "image/pjpeg") || ($data == "image/x-png") || ($data == "image/png"))) {

    if ($data["error"] > 0) {
        echo "No Picture upload";
    } else {

        if (file_exists("../uploads/" . $data)) {
            echo 'This picture already exists';
        } else {
            file_put_contents('upload/' . $imageName, $data);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_for_images . " (user_id, img_name, img_loc)
                       VALUES
                       ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "',
                       '" . $ImageName . "',
                       'uploads/" . $data . "')";

            if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
                echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
            } else {
                echo('Something went wrong');
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo('Something went wrong');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace $data with $imageName in your query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_for_images . " (user_id, img_name, img_loc)
                   VALUES
                   ('" . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "',
                   '" . $ImageName . "',
                   'uploads/" . $ImageName . "')";
```

Comment: Might be worth showing this using a code snippet so people can see the context.